# Deploying a WCF service to IIS 7 64bit

Tags: wcf

I'm working on a WCF service and and Im testing it out in Cassini. I also have a console app and has a web ref. to the svc hosted in cassini. This works fine and I'm able to invoke to service method. But when I deploy the svc to IIS and I try to run to console app I'm getting this error.

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 was unhandled
>   Message=There was an error in deserializing one of the headers in message NotifRQRequest.  Please see InnerException for more details.
>   Source=mscorlib
>
> Server stack trace:
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>   Exception rethrown at [0]:
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>   at TestConsole.ServiceReference1.IPush.RQ(NotifRQRequest request)
>   at TestConsole.ServiceReference1.PushClient.TestConsole.ServiceReference1.IPush.NotifRQ(NotifRQRequest
>   request) in ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:line 37165
>   at TestConsole.ServiceReference1.Client.RQ(Security Security, Action Action, MessageID MessageID, ReplyTo ReplyTo, To To,
>   NotifRQ notifRQ1) ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:line 37176
>   at TestConsole.Program.Main(String[] args)
>   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean 
>   ignoreSyncCtx)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   InnerException:

I'm running a x64 envt. and even tried changing to different app pools.

Any suggestions or hinds would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

EDIT 1:
Just noticed one thing. The svc uses about 5 xml namespaces that are listed in the wsdl. In cassini, I can browse then i.e. I can hit localhost/Notification/NotificationService.svc?xsd=xsd0 but I cant do the same on IIS!!!

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05/Imports">
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost/Notification/NotificationService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"/>
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost/Notification/NotificationService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"/>
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost/Notification/NotificationService.svc?xsd=xsd3" namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing"/>
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost/Notification/NotificationService.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"/>
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://p/Notification/NotificationService.svc?xsd=xsd4" namespace="http://htng.org/2011A"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

EDIT 2:
It appears that this seems to be happening only on a 64 bit machine and works fine on a 32bit.

Comment: Really need to see the InnerException to get an idea of what the problem actually is. Can you edit to add it please?

Comment: Are you able to browse to the endpoint directly using internet explorer? Do you get any errors while doing that?

Comment: Yes I'm able to browse and view the wsdl

Comment: There's nothing in the inner exception its empty!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an issue with the Redirect module configuration specified in web.config